# How Add Attribute To HTTP request Using middle ware

Tags: django, django-middleware

hi i want add attribute to Django **HttpRequest objects** by using custom **Middleware** like request.user
how i can do that ? can any one give me some resources how to do that ?

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    nickname = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    location = models.CharField(blank=True, null=True, max_length=50)
    avatar = models.ImageField(null=True)
    weight = models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    website = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
```

i want add profile object as attribute to request the result i want is request.profile

Comment: Why? You can get profile just writing `request.user.profile`.

Comment: thanks for your solution but i want direct access to profile object